# wget to get a file generated by a php script

Tags: php, downloads, wget

I am trying to get a file generated by the php script export.php. But using this command, I am either getting 403 Request Forbidden or downloading the script itself instead of a .csv the script is supposed to generate. If I visit the link manually on Chrome, the download starts automatically and the csv file is downloaded

```
wget -U Chrome http://proto.agrech.com/export.php
```

Comment: You're creating some redirection, which wget isn't going to follow.  How is the data generated to be downloaded?

Comment: It looks like JS?  curl nor wget will work with javascript.

Comment: Maybe use something like Selenium or PhatomJS?

Comment: Solved by getting the CURL command to go from the browser to download the .csv.

Answer (score -2):

Solved by getting the CURL command to go from the browser to download the .csv

Comment: and the curl command is...?